# Retrieve all lists and libraries Sharepoint Online

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, visual-studio, custom-list, caml-query

I'm trying to retrieve all lists from my online tenant from Visual Studio. After much fumbling and unsuccessful attempts with:

```
ListItemCollection listItemCollection = oList.GetItems(query);
```

and

```
context.Load(listItemCollection, items => items.IncludeWithDefaultProperties(item => item.DisplayName));
```

I arrived at this (feel free to criticize, it's all welcome):

```
            ClientContext context = new ClientContext(url);
            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, password);

            Web site = context.Web;
            context.Load(context.Web.Webs);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            for (int i = 0; i < site.Webs.Count; i++)
            {
                context.Load(site.Webs[i].Lists);
            }
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            string lists = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < site.Webs.Count; i++)
            {

                lists = lists + context.Web.Webs[i].Url + "\n";
                for (int j = 0; j < context.Web.Webs[i].Lists.Count; j++)
                {
                    lists = lists + context.Web.Webs[i].Lists[j].Title + " " + context.Web.Webs[i].Lists[j].Created + " " + context.Web.Webs[i].Lists[j].ItemCount + "\n";
                }

                lists = lists + "\n\n\n";
            }

            Console.WriteLine(lists);


            context.Dispose();
```

**Is it correct to use context.Load() in a loop?**
If I don't load all the lists beforehand the for loop gives me "uninitialized error".
**Is it correct to use context.ExecuteQuery() multiple times?** 
Which direction should I be going? Considering that it needs to authenticate/server load/application speed, should I use smaller and often queries or should I rather try to gather more .Load() and run it in single .ExecuteQuery()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since CSOM supports [Request Batching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798420.aspx) that allows to minimize the number of messages that are passed between the client and the server, it matters how operations are submitted to the server using `ClientContext.ExecuteQuery` method:

- `ClientContext.ExecuteQuery` method performs the actual request to the server, it could contain single or multiple operations. So, the best practise is to minimize the number of calls using `ClientContext.ExecuteQuery` method.
- You could use the `ClientContext.Load` method as many times as needed
  since it only *tells the client context object what to return when it
  executes a batched request*.

### Further steps for optimization

Instead of:

```
Web site = context.Web;
context.Load(context.Web.Webs);
context.ExecuteQuery();

for (int i = 0; i < site.Webs.Count; i++)
{
     context.Load(site.Webs[i].Lists);
}
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

you could use the following way of loading Lists for a sub Webs:

```
context.Load(context.Web.Webs,wc => wc.Include(w => w.Url, w => w.Lists));
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

So, instead of retrieving sub webs and lists in a separate requests, you could combine both operations to perform a single request.

Comment: Thank you Vadim, you are helping me once again. Let me test and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Great, hope this helped you